# How to dynamically add data from a list to a database (PostgreSQL)

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, psycopg2

DataBase is already created(PostgreSQL)

There is a list:

```
data = 
['param_1', 0], 
['amp', 0], 
['voltage', 1], 
['params', 1], 
['antenna', 1], 
['freq', 0.00011000000085914508]
```

I tried that

```
import psycopg2
from psycopg2 import sql 

    with psycopg2.connect(dbname='db_name', user='postgres',
                      password='123', host='localhost') as conn:
        conn.autocommit = True
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            query = "INSERT INTO table_name (%s) VALUES (%s);"
            cur.executemany(query, data)
```

I need to insert values in the table in the database that contains fields named: `'param_1': 'paRam_2' e.t.c.`

How do I generate a query string?

I will be happy for any help, thanks in advance, stack.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So you want to insert a single row with those numeric values written to the corresponding columns?

Comment: @GordThompson, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameter substitution can only be used to pass column *values*, not column *names*, so we'll need to build a list of column names to insert into the SQL command text. Specifically, we'll need to

1. build a comma-separated string of column names
2. build a comma-separated string of parameter placeholders
3. create the INSERT command, including the two items above
4. create a tuple of (numeric) parameter values
5. execute the command

That would look something like this:

```python
# create environment
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
data = (
['param_1', 0],
['amp', 0], 
['voltage', 1], 
['params', 1], 
['antenna', 1], 
['freq', 0.00011000000085914508]
)

# example code
# ~~~~~~~~~~~~
columns = ','.join([f'"{x[0]}"' for x in data])
print(columns)
# "param_1","amp","voltage","params","antenna","freq"

param_placeholders = ','.join(['%s' for x in range(len(data))])
print(param_placeholders)
# %s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s

sql = f"INSERT INTO table_name ({columns}) VALUES ({param_placeholders})"
print(sql)
# INSERT INTO table_name ("param_1","amp","voltage","params","antenna","freq") VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)

param_values = tuple(x[1] for x in data)
print(param_values)
# (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0.00011000000085914508)

cur.execute(sql, param_values)
```

Comment: Thank you very very much

Answer (score 0):

Thank's @GordThompson for his response. It's been very helpful and based on your response I have created two functions:
 - One for reading string of falues.
 - Second to insert values into the    table.

I would like to notice that psycopg2 did not fight for a dynamic lookup of the table name in the query string generation

```
import psycopg2

def insert_to(self, table_name: str, data: dict):
    # формирование строки запроса
    columns = ','.join([f'"{x}"' for x in data])
    param_placeholders = ','.join(['%s' for x in range(len(data))])
    query = f'INSERT INTO "{table_name}" ({columns}) VALUES ({param_placeholders})'
    param_values = tuple(x for x in data.values())
    try:
        self.cur.execute(query, param_values)
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(f'\r\nException: {e}')
    else:
        log.warning(f'INSERT INTO "{table_name}" {data}')


def read_from(self, table_name: str, dict_for_get_pk: dict) -> any:
    # формирование строки запроса
    columns = ','.join([f'"{x}"' for x in dict_for_get_pk])
    param_placeholders = ','.join(['%s' for x in range(len(dict_for_get_pk))])
    query = f'SELECT * FROM "{table_name}" WHERE ({columns}) = ({param_placeholders})'
    param_values = tuple(x for x in dict_for_get_pk.values())
    try:
        self.cur.execute(query, param_values)
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(f'\r\nException: {e}')
    else:
        db_values = self.cur.fetchall()
        if db_values:
            return db_values[0]
        else:
            return None
```